# File.exists() returns false for file (directory) that actually exists

Tags: java, android, file

**TLDR: `File.exists()` is buggy and i would like to understand why!**

---

I am facing a weird issue (as so often happens) in my Android App. I will try to be as brief as i can.

First, i will show you the code and then provide some additional info. This is not the full code. Just the core of the issue.

Example code:

```
String myPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Documents";
File directory= new File(myPath);
if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not create the specified directory: " + directory.getAbsolutePath() + ".");
}
```

**Most of the time** this works fine. **A few times** however the exception is thrown which means that the directory did not exist **and** could not be created. Out of every 100 runs, it works fine on 95-96 times and fails 4-5 times.

- I have declared the permissions for storage/read external storage/write external storage in my manifest **and** asked for the permissions on runtime. The problem does not lie there. (If anything i have too many permissions at this point :D ). After all, if it was a permission issue it would fail every time but in my case it fails at a rate of 4% or 5%.
- With the above code i am attempting to create a file that points to the 'Documents' folder. In my app i am actually using `String myPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getPath();`
  In the specific device where the error occurs this path happens to be "/storage/emulated/0/Documents" and **this is why i hardcoded it** in the example code i gave you.
- If i use a file explorer app on the device (i.e. 'Astro file manager' i can see that the folder does **exist** and has some contents and also confirm that the path **really** is "/storage/emulated/0/Documents".
- This has never happened to me locally. Only the users of the app experience the issue and i know the issue exists thanks to Firebase/Crashlytics. The users have the **exact same tablet** as the one i am using for development, namely a Lenovo TB-8504X. (I work for a company and we provide both the software and the hardware).

So, do you have any thoughts on why this issue occurs?

Has anyone ever experienced something similar?

Could the path to the 'Documents' folder sometimes be "/storage/emulated/0/Documents" and sometimes become something else **on the same physical device**?

I am an experienced Android developer but i am quite novice in Android architecture and the Android filesystem. Could it be that on start-up (when device is powered on or after a reboot) the filesystem has not yet 'mounted' the 'disk' at the point when my code checks if the directory exists? Here i am using the terms 'mount' and 'disk' as loosely as possible. Also my app is actually a launcher/parental control app so it is the first thing that gets fired when device starts. I am almost conviced that this does not make sense at all but at this point i am trying to see the greater picture and explore solutions that transcend typical Android development.

I would really appreciate your help as this issue is starting to get on my nerves.

Looking forward to any helpful responses.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT (27/08/2019) :**

I came across this [Java Bug Report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5003595) although it is pretty outdated. According to this, when operating on NFS-mounted volumes, `java.io.File.exists` ends up performing a `stat(2)`. If the `stat` fails (which it may do for several reasons), then `File.exists` (mistakenly) assumes that the file being `stat'ed` does not exist.  Could this be the source of my troubles?

**EDIT (28/08/2019) :**

Today i am able to add a **bounty** to this question in an attempt to draw some more attention. I would encourage you to read the question carefully, look through the comments **disregarding** the one that claims that this has to do with costumer support from Realm. Realm code is indeed the one using the unreliable method but **what i want to know** is why the method is unreliable. Whether or not Realm can work around this and use some other code instead, is beyond the scope of the question. I simply want to know if one can safely use `File.exists()` and if not, **why**?

Once again, thank you all in advance. It would be really important to me to get an answer even if it is overly technical and involves a deeper understanding of NFS file systems, Java, Android, Linux, or whatever!

**EDIT (30/08/2019) :**

Because some users suggest replacing `File.exists()` with some other method, i'd like to state that what i am interested in at this point **is understating why** the method fails **and not** what one could use instead as a workaround.

**Even if i wanted to replace** `File.exists()` with something else, **i am not able** to do that because this piece of code resides in `RealmConfiguration.java` file (Read-only) which is part of the Realm Library that i use in my app.

To make things even more clear i will provide two pieces of code. The code i use in my activity and the method that get's called in `RealmConfiguration.java` as a consequence:

*Code i use in my activity :*

```
File myfile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Documents");
if(myFile.exists()){        //<---- Notice that myFile exists at this point.        
   Realm.init(this);

   config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
   .name(".TheDatabaseName")
   .directory(myFile)       //<---- Notice this line of code.
   .schemaVersion(7)
   .migration(new MyMigration())
   .build();

   Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
   realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();        
}
```

At this point myFile exists and the code that resides in `RealmConfiguration.java` get's called.

*The `RealmConfiguration.java` method that crashes :*

```
    /**
         * Specifies the directory where the Realm file will be saved. The default value is {@code context.getFilesDir()}.
         * If the directory does not exist, it will be created.
         *
         * @param directory the directory to save the Realm file in. Directory must be writable.
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code directory} is null, not writable or a file.
         */
        public Builder directory(File directory) {
            //noinspection ConstantConditions
            if (directory == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-null 'dir' required.");
            }
            if (directory.isFile()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("'dir' is a file, not a directory: " + directory.getAbsolutePath() + ".");
            }
------>     if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {   //<---- Here is the problem
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not create the specified directory: " + directory.getAbsolutePath() + ".");
            }
            if (!directory.canWrite()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Realm directory is not writable: " + directory.getAbsolutePath() + ".");
            }
            this.directory = directory;
            return this;
        }
```

So, myFile exists in my activity, the Realm code get's called and suddenly myFile no longer exists.. Again i wish to point out that this is not consistent. I am noticing crashes at a rate of 4-5% meaning that most of the time myFile exists both in the activity and when the realm code makes it's check.

I hope this will be helpful.

Again thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you allowed permission to read/write(android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) storage?

Comment: Yes my friend i did and i also mention it in my answer. The problem almost definitely does not lie there.

Comment: The path to the document folder varies for different user accounts on the device. Not sure your problem has anything to do with multiple users, just putting it out there.

Comment: @Vesper  Indeed my problem isn't related to multiple user accounts but thanks for your input mate.

Comment: How do you know that its `exists()` that returns false, and not `mkdirs()`?

Comment: If `!exists()` returned `false` , `mkdirs()` would not get evaluated.  `False && undefined = false`.

Comment: @SotirisS.Magionas `false && *anything* == false`, but if the directory doesn't exist and needs creating, `exists()` should return `false`, which makes `!exists()` *true.*

Comment: @user207421 Haha! Yeah i missed a '=' there. But you got what i meant!

Comment: I would remove the `exists()` test altogether and just leave the `mkdirs()` call. And ignore whether it succeeded or failed. Then the actual attempt to open the file will give you an exception with a meaningful error message, if and when it fails. Until you get that, and post it here, we are all just guessing.

Comment: Thing is, the code that uses `exists()` is not part of my code. It is part of the Realm Database code. Namely, it belongs to the `RealmConfiguration.java` class at line `534`. There is no way for me to change it other than get in touch with the Realm Dev Team and ask them to use something else instead if `exists()`.  Here is the link to that class on Github : https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.java

Comment: In that case your question is about product support, not computer programming, and is therefore off topic. Take it up with the vendor. Show them this page for how to do it night.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the solution requires product support, not computer programming.

Comment: In order to talk the Realm Dev Team into replacing `exists()` with something else i must first confirm that this is the issue. My question has to do with `exists()` behaviour and this definately is about computer programming and Java in particular. If `exists()` is unreliable, Java should be updated to fix this issue or at least mention this unreliable behaviour so that developers avoid using it or do it with caution including the Realm Dev Team. But once more, i am not 100% sure that this is the source of the issue. Perhaps i am missing something else. Hence i made a question...

Comment: To put it another way. Why does `exists()` behave the way it does at the example code i provided? What is the underlying reason? Regardless if i use the `exists()` method in my native code or through a library the question remains and holds value. Tomorrow i may need to use `exists()` in another project directly. Should i or should i not and why?

Comment: First of all, I would not remove `exists` from anywhere; the method is there for a reason. Second, this is a valid programming question that has nothing to do with "contacting a vendor". [The Java SDK for Realm is open source](https://github.com/realm/realm-java), so you can actually look at it and fork it if you want (what is proprietary is the DB itself among other things). The OP is raising valid concerns. I would point the RealmDB people to this (they read SO more often than not, and are known for answering questions, or used to in 2015 when I used it). Good luck.

Comment: As of why is this behavior a thing, well, I'm not sure, but RealmDB is know for doing a lot of things on the main thread because it's fast, and so maybe this is a rare case where sometimes the filesystem is slow enough that you get this strange behavior; this is just a theory. I haven't touched realmdb in a couple+ of years; if you look at the file you linked, they clearly say: _WARNING: This method is just a point-in-time check. Unless protected by external synchronization another thread or process might have created or deleted the Realm file right after this method has returned._

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Thanks for your input mate and thanks for supporting the validity of the question. I will continue my research on the matter and try to keep this thread here alive by offering a bounty but eventually i will indeed take this issue up with the Realm Dev Team.

Comment: @Sotiris One potential problem of your code is IMHO the usage of `mkdirs()` instead of `mkdir()`. On a regular computer `mkdirs()` makes sense, but here it may only cause trouble because none of the other directories in `/storage/emulated/0/` can be created. If they don't exists the problem is located somewhere else.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your input mate. I understand your point. However, to get to the point to call `mkdirs()` the code has evaluated `!directory.exists()` as true (meaning that the **directory does not exist**) when i can reassure you it **does** exist. This is the core of my question. Why is `File.exists()` mistaken?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, if you are using Android, bug reports in the Java Bugs database are not relevant.  Android does not use the Sun / Oracle codebase.  Android started out as a clean-room re-implementation of the Java class libraries.

So if there are bugs in `File.exists()` on Android the bugs would be in the Android codebase, and any reports would be in the Android issue tracker.

But when you say this:

> According to this, when operating on NFS-mounted volumes, java.io.File.exists ends up performing a stat(2). If the stat fails (which it may do for several reasons), then `File.exists` (mistakenly) assumes that the file being stat'ed does not exist.

1. Unless you are using NFS, *that* bug report is not directly relevant.
2. It is not a mistake / bug.  It is a limitation.
3. At the file system level, it is a fact of life that Linux supports many different kinds of file system, and that many of them behave in unexpected ways ... compared to an "ordinary" file system.  It is not possible for the JVM to hide all of the weird filesystem-specific edge cases at the Java API level.
4. On the API level, `File.exists` *cannot* report any errors.  The signature doesn't allow it to throw an `IOException`, and throwing an unchecked exception would be a *breaking* change.  All it can say is `true` or `false`.
5. If you want to distinguish the various reasons for a `false`, you should use the newer `Files.exists(Path, LinkOptions...)` method instead.

> Could this be the source of my troubles?

Yes it could, and not just in the NFS case!   See below.   (With `Files.exist`, an NFS `stat` failure would most likely be an `EIO`, and that would raise an `IOException` rather than returning `false`.)

---

The [File.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/luni/src/main/java/java/io/File.java) code in the Android codebase (version android-4.2.2_r1) is:

```
public boolean exists() {
    return doAccess(F_OK);
}

private boolean doAccess(int mode) {
    try {
        return Libcore.os.access(path, mode);
    } catch (ErrnoException errnoException) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note how it turns any `ErrnoException` into a `false`.

A bit more digging reveals that the os.access call is performing a native call which makes an `access` syscall, and throws `ErrnoException` if the syscall fails.

So now we need look at the documented behavior of the access syscall.  Here's what `man 2 access` says:

1. *F_OK tests  for  the  existence  of  the
      file.*
2. *On error (at least  one  bit  in  mode
      asked  for  a  permission  that is denied, or mode is F_OK and the file
      does not exist, or some other error  occurred),  -1  is  returned,  and
      errno is set appropriately.*
3. *access() shall fail if:*

   - *EACCES The requested access would be denied to the file, or search per‐
           mission is denied for one of the directories in the path  prefix
           of pathname.  (See also path_resolution(7).)*
   - *ELOOP  Too many symbolic links were encountered in resolving pathname.*
   - *ENAMETOOLONG
           pathname is too long.*
   - *ENOENT A component of pathname does not exist or is a dangling symbolic
           link.*
   - *ENOTDIR
           A component used as a directory in pathname is not, in  fact,  a
           directory.*
   - *<strike>EROFS  Write  permission  was  requested  for  a  file  on  a read-only
           filesystem.</strike>*
4. *access() may fail if:*

   - *EFAULT pathname points outside your accessible address space.*
   - *<strike>EINVAL mode was incorrectly specified.</strike>*
   - *EIO    An I/O error occurred.*
   - *<strike>ENOMEM Insufficient kernel memory was available.</strike>*
   - *<strike>ETXTBSY
           Write access was requested to an executable which is being executed.</strike>*

I have struck out the errors that I think are technically impossible or implausible, but the still leaves quite few to consider.

---

Another possibility is something (e.g. some other part of your application) is deleting or renaming the file or a (hypothetical) symlink, or changing file permissions ... behind your back.

But I don't think that `File.exist()` is broken<sup>1</sup>, or that the host OS is broken.  It is theoretically possible, but you would need some clear evidence to support the theory.

<sup>1 - It is not broken in the sense that it is not behaving differently to the known behavior of the method.  You could argue until the cows come home about whether the behavior is "correct", but it has been like that since Java 1.0 and it can't be changed in OpenJDK or in Android without breaking thousands of existing applications written over the last 20+ years.  It won't happen.</sup>

---

What to do next?

Well my recommendation would be to use `strace` to track the syscalls that your app is making and see if you can get some clues as to why some `access` syscalls are giving you unexpected results; e.g. what the paths are and what the `errno` is.  See https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/strace .

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar issue, but with a higher trouble rate, where the Anti Virus was locking `FileSystem`, and thus failing any requests (almost instantly)

the workaround was using `java.nio.Files.exists()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your input mate! I can confirm there is no Anti Virus software running on the device in question. Even if it existed and was restricting my access ,i assume it would do so every time. In my case the fail rate of the example code i provided is 4-5%. The rest of the time it works.

Comment: No, from my experience, and some internal testings (forced the behavior to happen), when the AVG was scanning a folder, all its ancestors were locked. I don't remember the failure rate, but was around a 5 nanoseconds window, where all requests failed (200 Threads doing `exists()` in a loop, outputting to System.err when failed). Replacing "fixed" the issue,

Comment: I see. However the device in question has no antivirus software installed so i cannot imagine how this can be related. At this point i want to say once more that i am not looking for a replacement for `File.exists()`. This method is called by some `Realm` code i use and i cannot alter it. I want to understand the conditions under which `File.exists()` returns an incorrect response. So your answer, researching the possible impact of an antivirus on the execution of `File.exists()`, is definately on the right track, but sadly not related to my issue.